# Its meaning vs. meaning of it

Tags: meaning, phrase-usage, usage

I often have seen using "meaning of *something*". So I understood I have to use "meaning of", but I saw following sentence:

> Its meaning is "Really?"

I am thinking why does the sentence use "its meaning"? What is the difference between "its meaning" and "meaning of *it*"?

Comment: I would just say *It means*

Comment: No difference,  but its is more common and idiomatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Its" is the possessive form of the personal pronoun "it".  You can say "meaning of something", but it's unusual or rare to use  the preposition "of" in front of a personal pronoun. Instead, you use the possessive form. For example:

Instead of saying "I don't know the meaning of it", you say "I don't know its meaning".  The use of "its" is far more common and idiomatic.

> Its meaning is "really".

In this sentence, "its meaning" is the subject.

The sentence is grammatical, but "It means really" is more common.